# PDF python text in wrong encoding

Tags: python, pdf

This is my code:

```
file = 'C:/Users/Karapuz/Desktop/ser/163687_BMW_X5_M1_0151_Маланюк Евро.pdf'
from pdfrw import PdfReader
x = PdfReader(file)
print(x.pages[0].Contents.stream)
```

This code produces the following:

> EKI0ô$¤<ú¶☻}Y'X»pj.Á♣ª§´,¶ïL↨↔¶µ£ñRÌA~²ä8→¾Î#;ng♣ç°6¢«FE¿♦êËG¥à´Y▲Ê♂qï4
> §sÀäF°»Îuß◄AÔJ=¤IêW↑³û▬ ¨m0¡òwgý¬ëxX¯èÈÁY.¿=áx(Áh¯°JQèë#2K|,

How can I get this information in normal encoding?

Comment: Have you tested whether you can successfully copy&paste from that PDF opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 0):

try using [ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/)

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader
import ftfy

file = 'C:/Users/Karapuz/Desktop/ser/163687_BMW_X5_M1_0151_Маланюк Евро.pdf'

x = PdfReader(file)
text = x.pages[0].Contents.stream
ftfy.fix_text(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pdfplumber`. [This](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) is their github page, you can find all the documentation that you want.

```
import pdfplumber
filename = 'path/to/your/PDF'
text = ''
pages = []
with pdfplumber.open(filename) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        text = text+str(page.extract_text())
        pages.append(page)
```

`text` will be a string containing all the text of your PDF, while `pages` will be a list of the object `page` (see documentation for more details).